# How to catch mousewheel up/down event using RaphaelJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, raphael

I need to implement a **horizontal** scrollable timeline. I've drawn the timeline/grids/rulers etc. I just need to catch mousewheel up/down to scroll the timeline (backward - past/forward - future).

First I need to catch the event: but nothing I've found seems to work. Need browser support only for chrome/firefox (latest versions).

These 2 won't listeners won't work:

```
var paper = new Raphael('raphael-paper');
// ...
paper.canvas.on('mousewheel', function(event) {     
    console.log(event);
});
// ...
paper.canvas.addEventListener('mousewheel', function(event) {
    console.log(event);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [jQuery mousewheel plugin - jquery.mousewheel.js](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel):

Usage:

```
// Init
var paper = new Raphael('raphael-paper');

// When Page Loads
$(document).ready(function()
{
    // capture mouse wheel using bind
    $(paper.canvas).bind('mousewheel', function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {
        console.log(delta, deltaX, deltaY);
    });

    // capture mouse wheel using the event helper
    $(paper.canvas).mousewheel(function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {
        console.log(delta, deltaX, deltaY);
    });
});
```